# How to set DatePicker is Enabled to false based on combobox selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

My question is that I'm creating one module for bill reminder and the problem that I facing is that I got one combo box with value such as "PAID" and "UNPAID". When the user choose the "PAID" from the combo box will enable the DatePicker so that will allow to pick the date.

What should I do to achieve this???

Answer (score 1):

On the selectedchange event of the combo, set

```
datepicker.Enabled = myComboBoxBox.SelectedItem != null && myCheckBox.SelectedItem == myItem
```

(or similar, maybe using SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem, according to your logic)

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the selection changed like this

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
```

And then in your code you can see wich option is selected an change the DatePicker IsEnabled property

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == 0) datePicker.IsEnabled = true;
        else datePicker.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Or

```
datePicker.IsEnabled = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == 0;
```